# DataTable autorefresh in every 30 seconds not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying an application to fetch records from db and populate dataTable using the returned json.

My app is working good but I want to refresh my table on every 30 seconds and to repopulated added/modified rows from db.

Ajax reload is not working. I need your suggestion to know where I am making mistake?

Here is my code..

Datatable Script

```
var table;

function submitData(){
    alert('Method Called');
    table=$('#table').dataTable({
        "pagingType" : 'full_numbers',
        "scrollY" : "200px",
        "dom" : 'TRlfrCtip',
        "colVis" : {
            "activate" : "mouseover",
            "restore" : "Restore"
        },
        "tableTools" : {
            "aButtons" : ["copy","csv","xls","pdf","print"],
             "sSwfPath": "http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        },
        "ajax" : {
            "url" : '../DataTableExample/FetchRows',
            "dataType" : "json",
            "type" : "POST",

        },
        "aoColumns" : [ {
            "mData" : "id",
            "sTitle" : "S. No"
        }, {
            "mData" : "name",
            "sTitle":"Name"
        }, {
            "mData" : "age",
            "sTitle":"Age"
        }, {
            "mData" : "designation",
            "sTitle":"Designation"
        }, {
            "mData" : "qualification",
            "sTitle": "Qualification"
        }, ],
        "deferRender": true,
        "columnDefs":[
        {
            "targets" : [0],
            "visible" : false,
            "searchable" : true
        }
        ]
    });



$('#table tbody').on('click','tr',function(){

    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});

    setInterval( function () {
        table.ajax.reload();
    }, 30000 );

}

function hideThings(){
    $('#table_length').css("display","none");
}
```

HTML

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>DataTable Example</title>
<!-- DataTables CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables-1.10.4/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables-1.10.4/media/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables-1.10.4/media/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables-1.10.4/extensions/ColVis/css/dataTables.colVis.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables-1.10.4/media/css/dataTables.colvis.jqueryui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables-1.10.4/media/css/dataTables.colVis.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables-1.10.4/extensions/ColReorder/css/dataTables.colReorder.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables-1.10.4/extensions/ColReorder/css/dataTables.colReorder.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables-1.10.4/extensions/TableTools/css/dataTables.tableTools.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables-1.10.4/extensions/TableTools/css/dataTables.tableTools.css">

<!-- Custom Javascript File -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="jsFiles/DataTableSamplejs.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="jqueryFiles/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="DataTables-1.10.4/media/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="DataTables-1.10.4/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="DataTables-1.10.4/extensions/ColReorder/js/dataTables.colReorder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="DataTables-1.10.4/extensions/ColReorder/js/dataTables.colReorder.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="DataTables-1.10.4/extensions/ColVis/js/dataTables.colVis.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="DataTables-1.10.4/extensions/ColVis/js/dataTables.colVis.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="DataTables-1.10.4/extensions/TableTools/js/dataTables.tableTools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="DataTables-1.10.4/extensions/TableTools/js/dataTables.tableTools.min.js"></script>

<!-- DataTables -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="DataTables-1.10.4/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submitData()"/>
    <table id="table" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
    <input id="hideButton" type="submit" value="Hide" onclick="hideThings()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you see any error in the browser console?

Comment: Ya it come as alert and update didn't reflect in the table.. But inside the function if it try to destroy the table if previously loaded it is working fine but the problem is on next refresh the table's state also getting changed. If is sorted the table on some columns it is reset to normal.. saveState is not working

Comment: How about resetting pagination or giving a false value. https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload%28%29

Comment: Not working.. I tried with that too.. actually ajax.reload is not working.. Is that any issues in my code??

Comment: Thats why I told you to see any error occuring in console. Firefox has a great built in developer tools. it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

OK 2 things,

One change

```
setInterval( function () {
        table.ajax.reload();
    }, 30000 );
```

to

```
setInterval( submitData , 30000 );
```

and

```
table=$('#table').dataTable({
        "pagingType" : 'full_numbers',
         destroy: true,    //ADD DESTROY TRUE
.
.
.
..
```

Comment: No, its not working.. It gives exception alerts and sometimes it shows old values and sometimes with new values appended with old values..

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it fetch every 2 seconds

```
setTimeout(function(){  $('#table').DataTable().ajax.reload();  },2000);
```

no need to destroy just reload table.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will reload the datatable every 30 second.

Change

```
setInterval( function () {
        table.ajax.reload();
    }, 30000 );
```

To

```
setInterval( submitData , 30000 );
```

Comment: submitData  or submitData () ??

Comment: No that's not working. It gives exception "DataTables warning: table id=table - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3" since it will reinitialize the table again

Comment: @RishiPrakash simply submitData is enough while calling in setInterval.. but that's not the solution for my problem.. As i explained above it tries to reinitialize the table again

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution..

I used event delegation to keep track on the column index in which sort performed and I applied it to "order" option dynamically using that variable. And as you guys suggested  I changed ajax.reload to call setInterval(submitData,30000) and inside that function I destroyed the table if found. Its working as expected now..

Thank you all for your support :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not necessary to destroy to reload the data. You can reload only the data

```
function reloadDatatable () {
    $('#example').DataTable().ajax.reload();
}; 
setInterval( reloadDatatable , 1000 );
```